# Proof that every global minima is also a bistable point

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Bistable point is defined as :

if(x1, y1) is a bistable point then :

f(x1,y) <= f(x,y) for all  x,y
and
f(x,y1) <= f(x,y) for all x,y

While the global minima is defined as :

if (x1, y1) is a global minima then
f(x1,y1) <= f(x,y) for all x,y

The book says every global minima is a bistable point, how can I prove it?

Comment: can you include an attempt :)

Comment: You know that every local minimum is a global minimum right?

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to add that this is not an academic question, rather I am self learning optimization from a book.

Also yea it seems like a trivial proof, but the way I have proved it is simply by substituting x1,y1 in terms of x, and y and so on which I am unsure if it's legal.